# Google Map overlay to disable scrolling doesn't work in Safari

Tags: html, css, google-maps, safari

I'm embedding a Google Map Lite map into my website and am looking to disable the scrolling feature.

I found a good solution to make a transparent overlay that goes directly over the map (see html and css below).

It works great in Chrome and Firefox, however in Safari there is just white space where the map should be. Is there a solution to this?

```
<html>
    <div class="overlay" onClick="style.pointerEvents='none'"></div>
    <iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=some_map_id" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
</html>

.overlay {
   background:transparent; 
   position:relative; 
   width:640px;
   height:480px; /* your iframe height */
   top:480px;  /* your iframe height */
   margin-top:-480px;  /* your iframe height */
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Place your `iframe` **within** your `div` (rather than after your `div`):

```
<div class="overlay" onClick="style.pointerEvents='none'">>
    <iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=some_map_id" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
</div
```

Comment: Thank you! Because it's an overlay, it needs to remain on top of the iframe. However, when I did more testing I realized it actually does work with safari, it was just my computer. I think this code is solid.